# Access denied when building a project

Tags: qt, mingw32

I’m working on a project with opencv lib. I use Qt 4.8 on Windows 7 and it gives me an error when building the project:

```
 mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** Access is denied.
 . Stop.
 mingw32-make.exe: *** [release] Error 2
 19:05:06: The process "F:\QtSDK\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
 Error while building project TraySystemtry (target: Desktop)
 When executing build step 'Make'
```

The pro file:

```
    QT += xml svg core gui

CONFIG += qt

VERSION = 0.3.0

TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include

LIBS += -LD:\OpenCV\opencv_Build\bin\
    -lopencv_core242 \
    -lopencv_highgui242 \
    -lopencv_imgproc242 \
    -lopencv_features2d242 \
    -lopencv_calib3d242 \
    -lopencv_objdetect242

HEADERS += \
    window.h \
    aboutus.h \
    abouttab.h \
    developertab.h \
    privacytab.h \
    classificationhand.h \
    keyssetup.h

SOURCES += \
    window.cpp \
    main.cpp \
    aboutus.cpp \
    abouttab.cpp \
    developertab.cpp \
    privacytab.cpp \
    classificationhand.cpp \
    keyssetup.cpp

RESOURCES += \
    systray.qrc
```

I can’t figure out the problem.

Comment: What does your build file look like? Did you try running it with admin privileges?

Comment: the same result @Bart

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least two possible causes:

1. The file you're trying to build is open/used (the program is running)
2. You don't have sufficient privileges (you don't have admin rights)

Cause #1 is often more likely than cause #2.

Answer (score 8):

I have the same problem. For mine, I resolved it just disabling the antivirus (Kaspersky). The antivirus was denying mingw32-make.

Comment: Thanks for the hint Armando... this was the same problem with me as well. Simply added it to the trusted list and things were again smooth as before.

Answer (score 0):

For me it usually means that the exe that I'm trying to compile is currently open (i.e., running). This often happens when I have it running in debug mode, then try to recompile.