# Make.exe Access denied

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am facing following two problems

**1**.Access is denied during ndk-build.

```
G:/AndroidApp/NativeCodes -> It has my native codes(c++) codes,when i try 
to build this,it is compiling the source files and creating the lib but at last
i am getting *make.exe: *** Access is denied..  Stop.*
```

**2**.And when i **launch** eclipse i am getting following two error in

```
 a) Android NDK: WARNING: There are no modules to build in this project!
 b) G:\AdroidApp\Meddiff: **Permission denied**
```

NDK which i am using is, r10c 32 bit.

**Problem solved by disabling antivirus.**

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer which worked for me on https://stackoverflow.com/a/17155381/1065835

A C file was opened in Eclipse and Beyond Compare. After I'd closed the latter, everything was build well.

My OS was Windows 8 (64-bit)